# IIS reading from the wrong location.. or is it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm having a rather unusual problem with a website I published.  The application feature that is broken is trying to open and read an XLSX file, which works fine in a dev environment.  When using the feature on test server (Windows 2012, IIS 8), it throws a null exception error.  I looked at the event log to get more information, but the message has something in it that's confused me.  I have pasted the log below.  As you can see where it says the null reference happened references an ExecuteAsync() in this location T:\Brdg_Websites.  The T drive (and the Brdg_Websites folder) is a shared folder the site was published from, but when I go into IIS and look at where it's running, it's running on C:\inetpub, which is the correct location.  Does anyone know why am I getting an error message reference the publishing location when I am running the site from IIS on a Windows server?

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware
EventId: 1
ConnectionId: 0HLS45L4CIEGS
RequestId: 0HLS45L4CIEGS:00000007
RequestPath: /File/Upload
SpanId: |3efe84f1-4e4a3e0ed4cbaae9.
TraceId: 3efe84f1-4e4a3e0ed4cbaae9
ParentId: 

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AspNetCore.Views_File_Upload.ExecuteAsync() in T:\Brdg_Websites\TicketingApplication_12_18_2019-02\Website\Views\File\Upload.cshtml:line 24
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Yes, it's a mapped drive to a network share folder (I'm not sure what the server specs are for the server it is on).  Basically we use it to store and move misc files from various servers to another.

Comment: Right.  However, IIS is actually pointing to c:\inetpub\ticketingapplication and not a shared directory.  The shared directory is just where the solution was running when it was published, but the publishing profile points to the website on the web server, and I've checked to make sure the website is running from the C drive.  In light of that, what I don't understand is why the error log is showing the error coming from the T drive.  I am running the site directly from IIS (going to IIS manage and choosing browse.  The browser is running from the address http://localhost:8080).

Comment: Sounds like it is simpler than I thought. Your code in `Upload.cshtml` around line 24 is not good enough to handle the exceptional cases. The T drive path is what the runtime picked up from symbol files, so usually that does not matter.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I was thrown off by the mention of a shared drive when my code (and IIS) weren't referencing it.  I thought the problem must be something deeper.

Comment: could you show your code where exactly that error has occurred?